# Trying to trap all memory reads/writes on a Linux machine

Tags: linux, unix, memory

I have a Linux machine and I am trying to catch all the writes or reads to the memory for a specific amount of time (I basically need the byte address and the value that is being written). Is there any tool that can help me do that or do I have to change the OS code?

Comment: I think there's ptrace and or hardware debuggers to do this

Comment: You do realize that every single instruction that executes is at least one memory read, right? Even a humble 1GHz system is going to generate a *lot* of trace data if you really want to catch "all the writes or reads". You might do well to narrow down exactly what you are looking for...

Comment: Hardware debugger (e.g. JTAG), some can catch read and/or write to a countable (small) number of locations that you would specify, yes. But probably you should explain your objective, e.g. what you mean by "all the writes or reads to the memory". Then we may explain why it won't work.

With software debugger e.g. GDB you could step or hit breakpoints with a watch on specific variables. But that does not sound like what you want.

Comment: I am actually interested in some specific regions of the memory (the physical memory). I am trying to catch all the reads and writes written to a specific memory region

Comment: Preferrably I dont want hardware debuggers. My last resort would be to change the OS code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mentioned that you only want to monitor memory reads and writes to a certain physical memory address. I'm going to assume that when you say memory reads/writes, you mean an assembly instruction that reads/writes data to memory and not an instruction fetch.

You would have to modify some paging code in the kernel so it page faults when a certain address range is accessed. Then, in the page fault handler, you could somehow log the access. You could extract the target address and data by decoding the instruction that caused the fault and reading the data off the registers. After logging, the page is configured to not to fault and the instruction is reattempted. Similar to the copy-on-write technique but you're logging each read/write to the region.

The other, hardware, method is to somehow install a bus sniffer or tap into a hardware debugging interface on your platform to monitor which regions of memory is being accessed but I imagine you'll run into trouble with caches with this method.

As mentioned by another poster, you could also modify an emulator to capture certain memory accesses and run your code on that.

I'd say both methods are very platform specific and will take a lot of effort to do. Out of curiosity, what is it that you're hoping to achieve? There must be a better way to solve it than to monitor accesses to physical memory.

Comment: Your answer is spot on and it is really what I was looking for. I am actually doing a research project. I am trying to trace the physical memory of some virtual machines, running on KVM. I could easily dump the whole physical memory space by snapshotting the VMs. Now I would like to have a memory trace for some regions in the memory for like thousands of cycles. I assume I will need to play with the KVM code for that which is kinda easier than my posted question, but I wanted to understand what if I want to trace the physical memory itself. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Self-introspection is suitable for some types of debugging.  For a complete trace of memory access, it is not.  How is the debug code supposed to store a trace without performing more memory access?

If you want to stay in software, your best bet is to run the code being traced inside an emulator.  Not a virtual machine that uses the MMU to isolate the test code while still providing direct access, but a full emulator.  Plenty exist for x86 and most other architectures you would care about.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you're just interested in memory reads and writes by a particular process (to part/all of that process's virtual memory space), you can use a combination of ptrace and mprotect (mprotect to make the memory not accessable and ptrace run until it accesses the memory and then single step).

Comment: Unfortunately, I dont really care about any process. I am also not concerned with the virtual address space. I am concerned about some regions in the physical memory and I just want to know when these regions are being read/written to

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to say, it's just not possible to do what you want, even if you change OS code. Reads and writes to memory do not go through OS system calls.

The closest you could get would be to use accessor functions for the variables of interest. The accessors could be instrumented to put trace info in a separate buffer. Embedded debugging often does this to get a log of I/O register accesses.

Comment: mmm isnt the OS responsible for translating the virtual address to physical address, and handling all the page table stuff. I think the OS is involved in every memory access!

Comment: @Keeto: No, the CPU has hardware that does that translation.  The OS just configures it.